# Adding Dependency Property from code

Tags: .net, wpf, dependency-properties, attached-properties

I have created custom Dependency Property for Window class. And I'm setting this property on TextBox in xaml as shown in code below.  The SampleProperty class extends the Windows class and not Stackpanel.

```
<StackPanel l:SampleProperty.IsSamplePropertyField="true"/>
```

How do I set this property from my code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you defined the attached property you created static getter and setters methods, which you can use in your code:

```
SampleProperty.SetIsSamplePropertyField(myStackPanel, true);
```

Comment: Should be SampleProperty.IsSamplePropertyField(myStackPanel,true)

Comment: @xxMUROxx All attached properties setters are prefixed with "Set" by convention, so it's in fact `SetIsSamplePropertyField`. Example: `ScrollViewer.SetIsDeferredScrollingEnabled`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I confused myself. I did instead mean myStackPanel.SetValue(SampleProperty.IsSampleProperty, true)

Comment: That's another option, but I find that using my option is better since the setter method sometimes has additional logic other than just setting the value.

Comment: The setter method should never have additional logic, it is bypassed when the attached property is used from XAML.

Comment: @NovitchiS This is true for CLR-accessors for regular dependency properties, but I'm not sure this is true for attached properties as well. Regardless, you are correct that having additional logic in the setters is a bad practice and should be avoided.